# Projective ideal of a Non-noetherian domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is an integral domain which is not Noetherian and let $I$ be an ideal which is not finitely generated. We have always, if I is invertible, then I is always projective. Is the converse true when $I$ is not finitely generated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is, and in both cases $I$ results to be finitely generated.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you. So we have for any ideal I of domain (may be Non-netherian), I is invertible if and only if I is projective.

Comment: Right! See Proposition 1.6 [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/Dedekind.pdf).